# Creating DLL using MASM32

Tags: dll, exe, masm32

I have a problem creating DLL in masm32. No matter what I do the output is always *.exe file, not the *.dll. The following codes are in fact those created by masm32 -> Code -> Create New DLL. I just use Project -> Build All to build it. What am I doing wrong guys ?

mydll.def

```
LIBRARY mydll
EXPORTS my_proc
; EXPORTS [your_exported_proc_name]
```

makeit.bat

```
@echo off
if exist mydll.obj del mydll.obj
if exist mydll.dll del mydll.dll
\masm32\bin\ml /c /coff mydll.asm
\masm32\bin\Link /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS /DLL /DEF:mydll.def mydll.obj 
del mydll.obj
del mydll.exp
dir mydll.*
pause
```

mydll.asm

```
; ¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤
    include \masm32\include\masm32rt.inc
    include \masm32\include\windows.inc
; ¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤

    ; -------------------------------------------
    ; Build this DLL with the provided MAKEIT.BAT
    ; -------------------------------------------

      .data?
        hInstance dd ?

      .code

; «««««««««««««««««««««««««««««««««««««««««««««««««««««««««««««««««««««

LibMain proc instance:DWORD,reason:DWORD,unused:DWORD 

    .if reason == DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH
      mrm hInstance, instance       ; copy local to global
      mov eax, TRUE                 ; return TRUE so DLL will start

    .elseif reason == DLL_PROCESS_DETACH

    .elseif reason == DLL_THREAD_ATTACH

    .elseif reason == DLL_THREAD_DETACH

    .endif

    ret

LibMain endp

My_proc proc 

    ret

My_proc endp

; «««««««««««««««««««««««««««««««««««««««««««««««««««««««««««««««««««««««««

  comment * -----------------------------------------------------
          You should add the procedures your DLL requires AFTER
          the LibMain procedure. For each procedure that you
          wish to EXPORT you must place its name in the "mydll.def"
          file so that the linker will know which procedures to
          put in the EXPORT table in the DLL. Use the following
          syntax AFTER the LIBRARY name on the 1st line.
          LIBRARY mydll
          EXPORTS YourProcName
          EXPORTS AnotherProcName
          ------------------------------------------------------- *

; «««««««««««««««««««««««««««««««««««««««««««««««««««««««««««««««««««««««««

end LibMain
```

Comment: Use the linker's /OUT option to name the file.

Comment: so it's just the name ? I can manually change .exe to .dll and it will work ? xD

Comment: In fact Portable Executable format is the same for both .exe and .dll files. An .exe file can also export functions and be loaded dynamically into another process just like .dll file. A typical difference is that .dll files have no Entry point (but can have initialization)

Answer (score 0):

If you have a license for Visual Studio then you can use visual studio for your masm32 programming, the details of how to setup Visual Studio can be found [here](http://scriptbucket.wordpress.com/2011/10/19/setting-up-visual-studio-10-for-masm32-programming/) after following the steps provided go to project properties and under configuration properties change configuration type to Dynamic Library.